# Customizing sdk list / sdk use in sdkman

Tags: java, sdk, sdkman

I'm using a non-public JDK legacy version - precisely jdk-6u171 and I'm wondering if there is a way to list and use my locally installed versions with [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/).

My current results to `sdk list java`:

```
===================================================================
Available Java Versions
==================================================================
    9.0.7-zulu                                                                    
    9.0.4-openjdk                                                                 
    8.0.172-zulu                                                                  
> * 8.0.171-oracle                                                                
    7.0.181-zulu                                                                  
    6.0.107-zulu                                                                  
    10.0.1-zulu                                                                   
  * 10.0.1-oracle                                                                 
    10.0.0-openjdk                                                                
    1.0.0-rc1-graal
```

What I meant is: to show this installed version here in this list and also to be able to execute, for example, `sdk use java 6.0.171-custom`

Is there a way to have it?

Thanks in advance,

Regards.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

By the Usage documents, a local version of an sdk can be installed with

```
sdk install <sdk> <local-version-name> <path-to-local-installation>
```

see [Usage](https://sdkman.io/usage#localversion)

Answer (score 9):

for example in ubuntu:

```sh
sdk install java java241 '/home/srdr/java/jdk-8u241-linux-x64/jdk1.8.0_241'
```